# Prove that $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = G_{\sigma(a)}$ and $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = 1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a permutation group on the set $A$ (i.e.,$G \leq S_A$), let $\sigma \in G$ and let $a \in A$. Prove that $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = G_{\sigma(a)}$.
Deduce that if $G$ acts transitively on $A$ then
$$\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = 1.$$

Usually I know that in order to show $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = G_{\sigma(a)}$, I want to show $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} \subset G_{\sigma(a)}$ and $G_{\sigma(a)} \subset \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} $. But I don't know how to go further.

---

**Further Progress**

So now I proved that $\sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = G_{\sigma(a)}$, so I want to show that
$$\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} =\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} G_{\sigma(a)} = \bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \{g \in G \;|\; g \sigma(a) = g \}=1,$$

Since $g$ needs to be disjoint with $\sigma(a)$ in order to preserve $\sigma(a)$. But both $g,\sigma(a) \in G$, so the intersection has to be identity.

---

Done, looks correct?

Comment: As you have now seen $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1}= \bigcap_{\sigma \in G} G_{\sigma(a)}$ and $G$ acts transitively on $A$ can you see that $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G_a \sigma^{-1} = 1.$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$G_{\sigma(a)}=\{g\in G|g\sigma(a)=\sigma(a)\}=\{g\in G|\sigma^{-1}g\sigma(a)=a\}=\{\sigma h\sigma^{-1}|h(a)=a\}=\sigma G_a\sigma^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you @Shuchang. But I have a question - why $G_{\sigma(a)}=\{g\in G|g\sigma(a)=\sigma(a)\}$?

Comment: Definition of stabilizer, isn't it?

Comment: Oh indeed! Thank you Shuchang!

Comment: I finished the proof Shuchang - looks right..?

Comment: For the first thing, maybe a typo in your last equality. And do you use the property of transitivity?